# Did Sasuke get all of Itachi's special abilities?

Tags: naruto

Itachi had special abilities with his Susano'o: Yata Mirror, Sword of Totsuka and Yasaka Magatama.
Because Sasuke has Itachi's eyes, wouldn't he be able to use those abilities as well?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Susano'o is unique to each user as well as their abilities. Therefore Itachi's eyes shouldn't affect Sasuke's Susano'o.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No. Those accessories of Itachi's Susano'o were found by him. Sasuke is shown to have created his own weapon in this form. Sasuke just used Itachi's eyes for the Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan. A contrasting example would be how Danzo stole Shisui Uchiha's eye.He was able to use his technique of Kotoamatsukami. Maybe it wasn't as powerful as Shisui's but nonetheless, he used it. The same can go for Kakashi and Obito's Kamui. I believe that Itachi's accessories to the Susano'o were found by him because Orochimaru, who appeared during the Itachi vs Sasuke fight, stated his surprise in Itachi having the weapon. Orochimaru's knowledge of the sword probably means that he was trying to get it too. The same goes for the Yata and the Yasaka.

Answer (score 0):

When sasuke met itachi as his reanimation form he used the Amaterasu against kabuto when itachi was trying to stop him too, but at the same time itachi used the forbidden jutsu the Izanami which sasuke did not know about. Sasuke still hasn't used it even after the fight between them too. This tells us that sasuke did not get all of itachi's ability. He used it as itachi said, to get his eyesite back. If someone get the eternal mongekyou sharnigan then the eyesight  of the wielder will not lose their eyesight anymore